# Update the server files using non-bare Git repository

Tags: git

I have a Linux server with Git installed. I'm developing a web application and I want to create a git repository on server at the website path (/var/www/apps/myapp) and then push my local repository changes to it.

When I created a non-bare repository at server and pushed the changes, I got this error:

> Refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master.
>   By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied,
>   because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent with what
>   you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match the work tree
>   to HEAD. etc.

It's recommended to  use bare repositories. I could successfully do it but my problem is that I want my server to automatically update the web application folder whenever a change is pushed. As I understand, when I use bare repositories, I have to clone the bare repository in the server again to get the real files. This way I have 3 repositories. Two at the server side (one of them is bare) and one at local.

I just want a read-only repository to which I can push my changes and it updates the web application folder contents at server side.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the server repo you must allow pushing to the current branch. Excerpt from `git help config`:

> receive.denyCurrentBranch
>
> If set to true or "refuse", git-receive-pack will deny a ref update to the currently >checked out branch of a non-bare repository. Such a push is potentially dangerous because >it brings the HEAD out of sync with the index and working tree. If set to "warn", print a >warning of such a push to stderr, but allow the push to proceed. If set to false or >"ignore", allow such pushes with no message. Defaults to "refuse".

So in the server git repo:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

On the server, in `.git/hooks/` rename `post-receive.sample` to `post-receive` and add the following lines to it:

```
export GIT_DIR=`pwd`
cd ..
export GIT_WORK_TREE=`pwd`
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This will update the website whenever you push.

Comment: Isn't it dangerous regarding data loss?

Comment: And some points: 1) I don't have post-receive.sample there but there is post-update.sample. 2) What does `pwd` mean?

Comment: I used `git push -f origin master` but the same result.

Comment: pwd is a command that prints the current directory. You can also work with the post-update hook. It's called for each pushed branch, but if you only push one, it's the same. Don't worry about data loss, as long as you don't add dynamic content to the git repo.

Comment: Thanks. Do have any idea why `push` command doesn't work even with `-f` command?

Comment: I'm just looking up the configuration option to allow it.